# Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, brightness, backlight

This morning I found that I cannot change the brightness of my Dell XPs 13 laptop's display anymore. I tried the following to change the brightness

- Use keyboard brightness keys
- Run the commands shown below
- Boot with kernel option acpi_backlight=vendor. This resulted in a dell_something folder being present in the /sys/class/backlight folder. Changing the brightness file in that folder does not help.
- Add 'intel_backlight' to xorg.conf
- Set "load legacy option ROM" BIOS option to enabled and "secure boot" to disabled
- Boot with kernel option i915.disable-pch_pwm=0
- Boot from a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 USB stick installation. I can still not control the brightness. This is strange as the laptop came preinstalled with 12.04. Maybe this a hardware problem?
- Install latest intel video driver

Any ideas why this broke suddendly? I've upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 in April and till yesterday the brightness keys were working fine.

Thanks!

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: I used some help from this blog: http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/ It worked on a dell. Not able to run it on an acer.Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found that article myself but I figured that solve the problem. The changes in the xorg.conf just make the brightness buttons work by echoing the appropriate value in thebrightness file. My problem, however, is that even when I manually changethe value the brightness does not changed.

Answer (score 32):

I got a fix for my dell 5521 laptop, working for Ubuntu 14.04 but will work for kernels v3.13+.

1. Open `/etc/default/grub`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. to change the line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
   ```
3. then save and exit and
4. run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. then reboot

The explanation is that ACPI adds its own back light control even if one is already present which is `intel_backlight`, adding this line forces CPI to use the Intel back light.

Comment: I can conform, that this fix my problem in up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04.1 TLS version.

Comment: Perfect. worked under ubuntu 16.04 (Dell XPS 13).

Comment: It worked on ubuntu 16.10, too. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: This did the trick on first reboot, but not anymore. The line you suggested is still present on /etc/default/grub. Any idea?

Comment: @Soullivaneuh Did you update your grub after changing that line?

Answer (score 11):

For me, solution listed [on bug report #1249219](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1249219/comments/30).

Basically it works creating the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file with the following lines:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "card0"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
        BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: It's very good answer :)

Comment: How can you do this without `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package?  The package is causing complications in some Zenbooks etc here http://askubuntu.com/a/816703/25388

Comment: This prevented my machine from booting

Answer (score 4):

I created a simply script:

```
touch /usr/bin/brightness
```

The contents as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This allows you to then run the following from the command line:

```
brightness 100
brightness 4000
```

The values depend on your max brightness values which you can get by running:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
```

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/brightness
```

I opted not to change the permissions of the brightness file and keep the `sudo` part for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Terminal, run `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
2. It will ask for password. Type your password.
3. Then, the text editor will pop up with `rc.local` file opened. It contains some stuff and in the end `exit 0`.
4. Before that `exit 0` line, add below commands to reduce brightness in Ubuntu:

   ```sh
   echo x > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   echo y | tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video?*/brightness # (optional) > /dev/null
   ```

   where 0 ≤ x ≤ 4882 and 0 ≤ y ≤ 10.
5. That's it. Save and restart your machine.

Comment: how/where did you find the maximum value?

Comment: You can get maximum value for your monitor's brightness with `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`

Answer (score 3):

I have read A LOT of articles

Here is what I did, as I've been struggling with this for a long time...

Creating and modifying `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file with the following lines...

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "card0"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
   BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

...didn't work at all

I was using `xbacklight` option for some time, but it didn't satisfy me, as I knew it must be possible with Linux native way.

I've tried many GRUB options without effect, so I was googling again and again, coming back to solve this issue.

Today I came to the solution, which is following:

1. You need to kill your display manager, to create new Xorg.conf file (because it runs X server):

   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (Dont panic, while your Window system is runing, you can go back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)
   - type`sudo service lightdm stop` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>(e.g. gdm, kdm, xdm)
2. Create new Xorg configuration file

   - type `X -configure` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - type `mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Start X Server (you can do it all without GUI via command line, but I was more comfortable with this aproach):

   - type`sudo service lightdm start` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>(e.g. gdm, kdm, xdm)
4. Modify Xorg.conf file

   - navigate to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and open Xorg.conf (in my case latest was xorg.conf.05312015) via leafpad (e.g. gedit, pluma)
   - search for `Section "Device"` and then for `Driver` (on my PC it said `Driver      "intel"` by default, but it could be something else, so change it to `intel`)
   - add line `Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"` after `Driver "intel"` (it doesn't really matter where, as long as it stays in Device Section)
   - save
5. Modify GRUB

   - `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` (e.g. leafpad, pluma...)
   - set to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="` (`acpi_osi=` did it for me, other options didn't work...)
   - in terminal type `sudo update-grub` and press Enter
   - or use GRUB customizer:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

[image: Grub customizer]

- press Save in upper left corner, which will update GRUB for you

  7. Restart and profit

Funny thing is, that code is exactly the same as in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, but that way it worked as expected!

Comment: Works for me!  In a Samsung ATIV Smart PC Pro XE700T1C

Answer (score 3):

This worked for Acer 5830TG in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

1. First make sure your system uses Intel Graphics card

   ```
   $ ls /sys/class/backlight
   intel_backlight
   ```

   At least `intel_backlight` should be mentioned
2. Now download and install Intel graphics driver and [follow instructions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2).
3. On the grub configuration file `/etc/default/grub` modify the following line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
4. Then update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Create and open the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
   ```
6. Add the following text:

   ```
   Section "Device"
           Driver      "intel"
           Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
           Identifier "card0"
   EndSection
   ```
7. Save and reboot.

Comment: adding of ` acpi_backlight=vendor` was enough (+restart). Ubuntu 18.04. Samsung R510

Answer (score 2):

I used [this](http://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu/) solution, it's very simple and easy:

- Install xbacklight
- Open Startup Applications
- Add a new startup item, (give it a name and in the command line type: `xbacklight -set 50`)

50 gave me the level of brightness I needed but you may need to experiment with the values for your particular system.

Comment: I find it easier to just use `xbacklight -set 50` in the terminal.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on mac dual boot ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue of `xbacklight` not being able to find the displays.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my Samsung laptop with my Ubuntu 14.04 and kernel 3.19.

For me the solution was setting the line in the configuration file `/etc/default/grub` as following:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=0"
```

and then updating settings:

```
sudo grub-update
```

If t will not help you can try to turn off Legacy (CMS) boot option in BIOS.

---

Before I was trying:

- Setting `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/80-backlight.conf` file
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"`

Comment: For me, adding `video.use_native_backlight=1` to `/etc/default/grub` is working. But I need to control brightness by `xrandr`, there is no slider visible in display settings anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It works for ubuntu 14.04 for me.
Minimum brightness setting:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Maximum:

```
echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Lenovo Ideapad Z500.

I found this trick that worked on my Ubuntu 16.04:

In the GRUB configuration file `/etc/default/grub` modify the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

by adding this string: `acpi_backlight=vendor`. In my case I removed `acpi-osi=linux` and replaced, so, in the end it was:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Update grub by running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then create an xorg configuration file like this:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/80-backlight.conf
```

and copy in it this text:

```
Section "Device"
     Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
     Driver      "intel"
     Option      "AccelMethod"     "sna"
     Option      "Backlight"       "ideapad" 
     BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save the file, and reboot.

---

Also you can try to use <kbd>Fn</kbd> brightness keys outside of Ubuntu (before it starts or in the BIOS settings). It could work.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575020/ubuntu-14-04-brightness-problem-lenovo-z500

here where i found my solution

Answer (score 1):

I found solution after years of searching and it's works very well.

Just added in  /etc/default/grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` string `acpi_backlight=video`.

Lenovo Ideapad Z500: Intel HD4000, GeForce 740m

Comment: This one worked for me.  Mine is an Intel and nVidia combo on an HP Envy laptop.  There is no onscreen meter displayed by the OS as the brightness changes with this solution, and the brightness changes veeeeeerrrrry gradually for me.  I had to hold the button down for many seconds to cycle from fully dark to fully lit.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04.

I believe this answer applies **only if the following two statements apply to your system**. Please don't waste your time if these statements aren't true:

1. `ls /sys/class/backlight/` returns `acpi_video0` and **exactly** one other, such as `intel_backlight`
2. `echo 450 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` makes your brightness about half, and `echo 900 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` makes full brightness.

   (Here you should be replacing `intel_backlight` with whatever you found in step 1 **and** replacing 450 and 900 according to your device's maximum brightness setting, which is found by the command `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` or your equivalent.)

In this case your problem is likely to be because the system has added the `acpi_video0` module incorrectly, and the brightness keys use this instead of `intel_backlight` (or your equivalent).

To solve this, you need to add the boot option
`acpi_backlight=none` which will remove the directory `acpi_video0`  from `/sys/class/backlight/`. The brightness keys now apply their logic to the only directory in `/sys/class/backlight/` which is what we want.

I gleaned this knowledge from this helpful page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight which states that "If you find that changing the `acpi_video0` backlight does not actually change the brightness, you may need to use `acpi_backlight=none`."

Comment: Actually the following have made my screen black until I've got an idea that my laptop is going to sleep all the time `echo 900 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. A hard restart was a remedy.

Answer (score 1):

## For MANJARO 18 users:

I have a LENOVO with hybrid GPU, but I'm using just the NVIDIA card. Brightness buttons didn't work. The edition sugester [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281886/backlight-control-doesnt-work-in-manjaro-with-nvidia-gf108glm-nvs5200m) with a `10-nvidia-brightness.conf` file didn't work. After reading a lot of, [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1249219/comments/30), from Ubuntu users, worked for me.

Open a terminal and type:

`ls /sys/class/backlight`

For me, it pointed to `intel_backlight`. I don't know how this works for the `acpi_backlight`.
I createad the file

`sudo <text_editor> /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

Put your favourite text editor in `<text_editor>`, mine is xed.

Then write inside:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "card0"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
        BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

The correct PCI should be that from the output of `lspci | grep VGA` (mine is `00:02.0`). Save the file, then `sudo pkill X` (or reboot) and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04
brightness-hotkey-fix: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [ HD Graphics 520 ] (rev 07)

1. `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
2. save and update grub: `sudo update-grub`
3. `sudoedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

   Section "Device"

   Driver      "intel"

   Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"

   Identifier "card0"

   EndSection
4. save and reboot

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my eeepc seashell series:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

This is from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1412922,
and they got it from http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/Model/1005pe.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu 16.04 (Samsung N150 - Intel GMA3150):

Fixed brightness control issue by **creating** `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with the following text:

```
Section "Device"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        Identifier "card0"
EndSection
```

Thanks to:
[ArchLinux - Samsung_N150_Backlight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samsung_N150#Backlight) 
and
[Daria](https://askubuntu.com/a/536618/624852)

Answer (score 0):

clone the following script and run it from a root terminal after pasting the script in `/bin`

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/backlight.sh.git`

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this to expand it with an explanation of what you mean by "pasting the script in `/bin`"? Do you mean to copy it to that directory? Can you add instructions for the steps besides running `git clone`?

Answer (score 0):

So I've just solved this problem in my *Dell XPS 15 7590 (Ubuntu 18.04) with OLED screen* after setting up dual boot with it.

The screen can dim (for example power-saving dimming) so it's definitely capable, and using brightness buttons operates the visual slider, so those are definitely recognised. But it was at full intensity and nothing I tried would control it.

I tried lots of other fixes I've seen here including: grub editing with acpi_backlight=vendor, installing brightness controllers, echoing values into backlight files, even tinkering with intel vs nvidia drivers in case that was the issue etc. No joy.

I came across this info on setting up my model (XPS 15 7590, OLED screen) with Arch Linux where the brightness was an issue there, and tried following that method: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_7590#Backlight 
There was a script based on that (https://github.com/lurwas/oled-brightness-ubuntu) which looked helpful but didn't work for me.

Until I realised that in the ArchLinux page it mentions

> Please note: If you are using the xf86-video-intel driver, you will need to replace 'eDP-1' in the script above with 'eDP1'

Sure enough, my system seemed to be looking for instructions relating to 'eDP1' and everything else was telling it to change 'eDP-1'.  The dash made all the difference.

I set up that script as a start-up program, checking I had 'bc' and 'inotify-tools' installed as mentioned in the Arch Linux instructions (though note that page refers to 'itnotify-tool', and ubuntu required the 's' on the end to find/install it!) and made sure it had run permissions, and BOOM - "let there be LESS light!".

The script is run at start-up, and my backlight keys now actively change the screen brightness.

Hope this might be helpful, in case you have a similar underlying problem. I'm not sure if this fix is possibly just for an OLED-specific issue, so your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing GPU drivers fixed brightness control for me.**

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-detect
$ nvidia-detect
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:25b8] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation Device 25b8 (rev a1)
Your card is supported by the default drivers.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 460 drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.

$ sudo apt install nvidia-tesla-460-driver
$ sudo reboot
```

Hardware: Dell Precision 7560 laptop, NVIDIA RTX A2000 / GA107GLM.

The packages require non-free to be enabled in `sources.list`.

I tried the options that [yqbk mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/774379/111115), grub settings and xorg config, but none of these worked. I also couldn't read the correct brightness value from `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/{actual_,}brightness`. After driver installation, the directory is gone and `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/` appeared in its place; now setting `echo 10 > brightness` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically NOT possible to adjust the default brightness of a standard terminal in Linux, but if it were possible to modify the /sys/backlight/*/brightness file, you could change the brightness.

The /sys filesystem will complain of input/output errors if you attempt to write to files in the /sys directory.  The system also may revert to other additional and unintentional settings if a user attempts to continue to write to files in the /sys directory and in my case and actually made my screen darker (without the option of allowing me to write or modify the aforemention brightness file in the /sys directory).

Bottom-line: If you're looking to do about anything graphical or sound related on your computing device, look elsewhere beyond the purveyors of electronic diarrhea and the developers of open source operating systems such as Linux.  Linux just "isn't there" in terms of a decent desktop multimedia experience.  Everyone knows that, including Linus.  However, if you're looking for a decent server experience, Linux may be for you.