# Backlight issue on dell xps

Tags: backlight

I just installed Ubuntu on my dell XPS and everything seems to work fine but the backlight that is constantly turn off. 
I've tried several options read through previous posts but none of those worked. I also tried to install Intel graphic drivers for Ubuntu 14 but no result as well.

I am really not good at coding, do you have any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you're using? 14.04 or 14.10? Can you adjust the screen backlight with hotkeys?

Comment: 14.04 No Hotkeys neither slide bar are working

Answer (score 0):

This could be a typical backlight control issue. As a workaround, you could edit the following file with:
`sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

(You could substitute the **vi** with any other editor that you're familiar with)

Please change the following line:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"

Save it and run `sudo update-grub` and reboot to make the change take effect.

If that's the case, your backlight control should work as expected now.

If you're interested, more information could be found in comment #5 of [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04). It's mainly caused by the BIOS and the Win8 capability. And for 3.16 kernel (which is the kernel of 14.10, it will use the native backlight control interface by default, therefore it won't have this kind of issue)

Last but not the least, it would be great to open a bug against this issue with `ubuntu-bug linux` command. Report guideline could be found from this [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks P.-H. Lin I tried your solution (using gedit instead of vi since I am not able to use vi) but nothing changed! Do you have by chance any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just solved the problem upgrading to kernel 3.18