# Laptop brightness too low on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: gnome, nvidia, 14.10, brightness, backlight

recently I switched to Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 64 bits on my laptop and I'm having some issues with the brightness. At first I couldn't change with the hotkeys, but I have already fixed it. The problem now is that the brightness is too low, but the indicator, the settings and the files in /sys/class/backlight show that it is at max.

I have dual boot with W7 so I tried starting Windows just to make sure it is not a screen problem, but in Windows it works fine.

I'm using the Nvidia 331 proprietary drivers.

Does anybody knows how to set the brightness to it's actual max?
Thanks.

P.D.:My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Z500 with a i7-3632QM and a Nvidia GT645M.

Comment: I don't have the actual link handy, but I experienced something similar and AskUbuntu gave the advice of switching over to a different terminal window, adjusting the brightness, and switching back.  Try:
  Press CTRL - ALT - F1
  Adjust brightness up
  Press CTRL - ALT - F7

does that fix it?

Comment: Looks like you confuse the display backlight setting with color calibration. It's very difficult to give further advice without a model number of the laptop, please [edit] your question and add the information. There are 2 possibilities here: Either someone already found a fix or you need to report the issue as a bug yourself.

Comment: @Javier: Could you please respond to the comment above?

Comment: @RickChatham it didn't worked. Maybe it's a silly question, but, can I change the value of the file max_backlight to increase it?

Comment: @LiveWireBT you are right I was confusing backlight brightness with colour brightness, I'm sorry. I have already edited the question with the information, I hope it will be useful.

Comment: Yeah if it's a color brightness issue the fix I mentioned won't help.  Probably best to follow @LiveWireBT's advice.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [post in the Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1461569#p1461569), that suggests the following kernel parameter for the Lenovo Ideapad Z500:

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

Please try this and give feedback if this solved your issue.

Related:

- [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/q/19486/40581)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 brightness problem (Lenovo Z500)](https://askubuntu.com/q/575020/40581)

Comment: I has got better, but still a bit darker than in windows, maybe the rest is just a colour management thing?

Comment: @JavierSalcedo Then you should file a bug. http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/40581