# No systemd rc file?

Tags: permissions, 15.04, systemd

With upstart, I used to have the permissions of some files set at boot time via a shell script in `/etc/init.d/` (sym-linked, from `/etc/rc2.d/`):

```
link="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"
chgrp backlight "$link/brightness"
chgrp backlight "$link/bl_power"
chmod 664 "$link/brightness"
chmod 664 "$link/bl_power"
```

But since Ubuntu 15.04, with systemd, I don't know how to do that.

**Using systemd, which file(s) can be used to execute commands with root privileges at boot time ?**

Thank you

---

Thanks to JdeBP, I found a way to have the permissions set for files that are generated at each boot. It uses [tmpfiles.d](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html), a component of systemd:

I created a file named `backlight.conf` (the `.conf` matters) in `/etc/tmpfiles.d`, containing these lines:

```
# Type Path                                       Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
f /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 0664 root backlight -
f /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power   0664 root backlight -
```

Now, the two files `.../brightness` and `.../bl_power` have the right groupship, and the right writing rights.

(This solves my problem, but doesn't answer my question)

Comment: [Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html). What are you _actually_ trying to do?  And how do `systemd-backlight` and `tmpfiles.d` not achieve it for you?

Comment: I just want to be able to have some commands executed with root privileges at each boot. I don't specifically want a solution which uses systemd. It must just take into account that `upstart` can't be used.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps by adding these lines into `/etc/rc.local` and `sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`, which is the recommended action for init as well.

But I assume, that there should be better methods for controlling the backlight, e.g. here: [Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: It didn't work :(. Thank you anyway

Comment: It is definitely working.  `/etc/rc.local` is executed during boot from systemd.  But there should be a better method solving the backlight problem.

Comment: Probably one of the configuration files of systemd allows to require the execution of some files, such as `/etc/rc.local`.