# I can not increase or decrease the brightness of my screen on UBUNTU 15.10

Tags: drivers, laptop, brightness, 15.10

just wondering if anybody knows what's the problem. I use the brightness bar control with my keyboard or in options, the computer shows me the brightness bar increasing or decreasing but the screen is still at max brightness.

My computer is:
Gateway NV51M

CPU: Intel Pentium processor T4500

Graphic Card: Intel GM45 Express Chipset

OS: Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit

[Brightness bar changes but screen doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdXa9.png)

Please if anybody can help me, I'm frustrated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for days, I came to the solution on the last answer of  [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04).

I'd like to write the answer here but I don't know HTML. I'm sorry for the people who will find this answer. At least I want to help them writing the url.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it works for your Computer too. Some has written that it works for this [Gateway NV44 (ubuntuforums.org)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650074). S*he just used the given script: [link to the script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1773587&p=10926719#post10926719)

Open terminal and type (or use any other texteditor

```
mousepad ./backlight_d.sh
```

Insert to the skript

```
#!/bin/bash

old_b=9;
declare -i curr_b=240;
declare -i target_b=240;

while : ; do
b=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`;
delay="0.5"

if [ $old_b != $b ]; then
old_b=$b
let "target_b=$b * 20 + 12"
#printf "Target: %10d\n" $target_b
fi

hex_b=".";

if [ "$curr_b" -lt "$target_b" ] ; then
let "curr_b=$curr_b + 2"
if [ "$curr_b" -gt "$target_b" ] ; then
let "curr_b=$target_b"
fi

hex_b="-"
elif [ "$curr_b" -gt "$target_b" ] ; then
let "curr_b=$curr_b - 2"
if [ "$curr_b" -lt "$target_b" ] ; then
let "curr_b=$target_b"
fi

hex_b="-"
fi

if [ $hex_b != "." ] ; then
hex_b=`printf "%02X" $curr_b`
delay="0.005"
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=$hex_b
fi

sleep $delay
done
```

Save the file and close the editor.

Next is copying the file in /etc and change the file rights by (you may have to enter your password)

```
sudo cp ./backlight_d.sh /etc/ && sudo chmod +x /etc/backlight_d.sh
```

Open with a texteditor the rc.local

```
sudo mousepad /etc/rc.local
```

and add befor ***exit 0;***

```
nohup /etc/backlight_d.sh &
```

Save the file and close the editor.

> "restart your computer. According to that article, you should be able to adjust your brightness." [source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1773587&p=10926719#post10926719)

Comment: I came to the solution by another way but I appreciate so much your aid. Thank you