# Brightness control is not working

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, brightness

The brightness control in the settings does not work.
I have an Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (on a i5-3570K Processor) and run Ubuntu 14.04.03.

I followed the instruction given in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight for Intel HD, which is to create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/80-backlight.conf` with

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"     "sna"
    Option      "Backlight"       "intel_backlight" # use your backlight that works here
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

After a reboot it still does not work.

Also, I get

```
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
acpi_video0
```

Am I not supposed to get some Intel stuff instead?

From other instruction found in https://askubuntu.com/a/481501/481818 I added

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

to `/etc/default/grub`,

run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot, but still no brightness control.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.. This solution works for most of the people
http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/