# Make Ubuntu remember screen brightness level without xbacklight

Tags: scripts, brightness, backlight

The problem is that Ubuntu always resets the brightness level to maximum after every reboot. I installed the `xbacklight` utility, but commands like `xbacklight -get` or `xbacklight -set XX` don't work. I get nothing as the output.

Actually, I would like to make my Ubuntu remember the level of brightness that was used last. How exactly can I do that? Here's some information:

```
ls -l /sys/class/backlight/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 27 09:43 radeon_bl0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/radeon_bl0


ls -l /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 09:54 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 09:54 bl_power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 09:47 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Feb 27 09:54 device -> ../../card0-LVDS-1
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 09:43 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Feb 27 09:54 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Feb 27 09:54 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 09:43 type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 09:42 uevent

uname -r
4.2.0-30-generic
```

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301724/xbacklight-not-working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Actually, I would like to make my Ubuntu remember the level of
>   brightness that was used last. How exactly can I do that? Here's some
>   information:

**Introduction**

The script below addresses OP's need to store and restore screen brightness that was used last.  It works in conjunction with `the lightdm` greeter and is activated by `lightdm`. There's no requirement to use `lightdm`, so if you prefer to use a cron job, you can do so.

Basic idea:

1. Have the script stored somewhere (either by getting it here or through github)
2. Create `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` using the `sudo` privilege.
3. Make sure that file has 3 lines: `[SeatDefaults]` , `display-setup-script`, and `display-stopped script`. Look below for details. Script header also gives overview.

**Script Source**

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: March 7th, 2016
# Purpose: Script that will remember screen brightness
#          Must be used in conjunction with lightdm
#          Place the following 5 lines into /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
#
#           [SeatDefaults]
#           #display-setup-script = Script to run when starting a greeter session (runs as root)
#           display-setup-script = /home/USER/bin/sergrep/brightness.sh restore
#           #display-stopped-script = Script to run after stopping the display server (runs as root)
#           display-stopped-script = /home/USER/bin/sergrep/brightness.sh store
#
#           Basic idea is that you must give full path and either store or restore as an option 
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/739654/295286
# Tested on:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
# Version: 1.2 , added brightness limit, file creation
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
ARGV0=$0
ARGC=$#



store()
{
   cat "$SYSDIR"/*/actual_brightness > "$1"
}
#----------

# This function restores brightness. We avoid 
# setting brightness to complete 0, hence
# minimum is 10% that can be restored.

restore()
{
  MAX=$(cat "$SYSDIR"/*/max_brightness  )
  LIMIT=$((MAX/10)) # get approx 10 percent value
  VAL=$(cat "$1" )
  if [ "$VAL" -lt "$LIMIT"  ] ;
  then
       # avoid going bellow 10% of brightness
       # we don't want user's screen to be completely dark
       echo "$LIMIT" > "$SYSDIR"/*/brightness
  else
       echo "$VAL" > "$SYSDIR"/*/brightness
  fi
}
#------------

# This function works for initial run of the script; the script cannot set
# brightness unless datafile exists first, so here we create the file
# Initial value there will be whatever the current brightness on first
# reboot was

create_datafile()
{
  cat "$SYSDIR"/*/actual_brightness > "$1" 
}

puke(){
    printf "%s\n" "$@" > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
}

main()
{
  local DATAFILE="/opt/.last_brightness"
  local SYSDIR="/sys/class/backlight" # sysfs location of all the data

  # Check pre-conditions for running the script
  if [ "$ARGC" -ne 1  ];then
     puke "Script requires 1 argument"
  fi

  if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]   ; then
     puke "Script has to run as root"
  fi

  # ensure datafile exists
  [ -f "$DATAFILE"  ] || create_datafile "$DATAFILE"

  # perform storing or restoring function
  case "$1" in
     'restore') restore  $DATAFILE ;;
     'store') store $DATAFILE ;;
     *) puke "Unknown argument";;
  esac

}

main "$@"
```

**Getting and Setting up the Script**

You can either copy the script directly or follow these steps from the command line ( to open command line , press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>  )

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git
```

The script will be located in `/opt/sergrep/brightness.sh`, so we do a:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/sergrep/brightness.sh
```

to make it executable. Next, we need to set it up to work with lightdm. Create the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file , either by opening it with command line `nano` text editor (the command is `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` ) or graphical `gedit` ( `pkexec gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` )

Write to that file the following lines:

```
[SeatDefaults]
#display-setup-script = Script to run when starting a greeter session (runs as root)
display-setup-script = /opt/sergrep/brightness.sh restore
#display-stopped-script = Script to run after stopping the display server (runs as root)
display-stopped-script = /opt/sergrep/brightness.sh store
```

Save and exit

**Indepth Overview**

You've already discovered that you can write to `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` file directly , and you can also read in those values as well. Problem is that `/sys` is a virtual filesystem, so once you reboot, all the files in that filesystem disappear.

So you could store value in `/sys/class/backlight/*/actual_brightness` into a permanent file on every reboot. The question is how - via cron job, via lightdm, or via other means. Personally, I chose the `lightdm` route.

Basically we take advantage of lightdm's feature - being able to run a script before the greeter starts and after the session exits. The brightness is recorded to `/opt/.last_brightness` file and read from each time the script starts. We're essentially performing two actions with the same script, just by passing different arguments.

Comment: When you get back from holiday, ping me in chat.  I get :
`sudo keep-brightness restore
+ main restore
+ local DATAFILE=/usr/local/bin/.last_brightness
+ local SYSDIR=/sys/class/backlight
+ '[' 1 -ne 1 ']'
++ id -u
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' -f /usr/local/bin/.last_brightness ']'
+ case "$1" in
+ restore /usr/local/bin/.last_brightness
++ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
+ MAX=11
+ LIMIT=1
++ cat /usr/local/bin/.last_brightness
+ VAL=1
+ '[' 1 -lt 1 ']'
+ echo 1` with set -x after the comments but it doesn't restore...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

1. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
2. add this line to the file (substitute X with the desired level of brightness):

   ```
   echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   ```

Comment: Well, I don't have "intel_backlight" in /sys/class/backlight/.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This answer will *set* brightness to certain predefined level, not record *and* restore brightness  as OP requested. This is only partial solution

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I'm going to answer my own question just for future reference. In my case, what I did is add the following lines (it's really just one line with a bunch of comments to remind me why and what I did there) to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0`:

```
# The following line should solve the problem of Ubuntu resetting
# the brightness level back to maximum after every reboot.

echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

This is what the entire file looks like now:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# The following line should solve the problem of Ubuntu resetting
# the brightness level back to maximum after every reboot.
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness

exit 0
```

Although I'm not one hundred percent sure if this is the best way to do it, everything seems to be working just fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to set the brightness with a command, making the brightness level change to a particular value at startup is easy. Do the following:

- Open Dash by pressing Super/Windows key
- Enter "Startup Applications" and press enter
- Click "Add"
- Enter a name (irrelevant) and the command
- Click "Add"

This should execute that command on startup. I am unsure of how to make it remember the previous brightness, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use light instead...
Otherwise it is a mess to fix it, especially if you have intel and nvidia graphics together!

This Works on Ubuntu 16.04... and is tested on Alienware M14XR2

Checkout->https://github.com/haikarainen/light

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please [edit] your answer and expand it a bit to include download and install instructions...