# Backlight too low on Ubuntu 16.04 (Lenovo Laptop)

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, lenovo, brightness, backlight

I can't get the brightness control to work properly on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation. My laptop screen appears really dark, but my second monitor works well. I've already tried a lot of alternatives (some are listed below) but I still had no luck on this matter. My Laptop is a Lenovo Z400 with a NVidia 630M.

I tried so far:

- Change and update the grub with the following line:
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
- Also tried GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"as suggested here [Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04)
- Create a file 20-intel.conf as suggested here: https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/
- Install xbacklight and set the brightness there (xbacklight -set ***XXX***) . It doesn't work at all
- Set the backlight max level manually to /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness (doesn't change anything)

Before the upgrade I was using Ubuntu 15.10 and the brightness control was working properly, but I've never been able to set the screen brightness at the same level than my Windows installation. This is something that I've never understood as well.

> ```
> ls /sys/class/backlight/
> intel_backlight
> ```

I really appreciate any help!

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! After a few days trying to sort out this issue, I found out that I had my ideapad_laptop module blacklisted on /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf . It was due to a Bumblebee installation tutorial that I followed few days ago. So removing ideapad_laptop from my blacklist.conf solved the problem.

Maybe one of the solutions I listed on the question works. So this topic serves as a compilation of few tricks to sort related problems.

Comment: I tried all of the above on an Asus LXD550 including removing asus_laptop from the blacklist and I had no success :(

Answer (score 0):

clone this repo and paste the script into the `/bin` directory. then make the script executable by using the following script.

`sudo chmod +x /bin/backlight.sh`

here is the repository for the script:

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/backlight.sh.git`

for more info read the `README.md` file in the cloned directory.