# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly no backlight at login screen

Tags: lenovo, screen, ubuntu-gnome

When my Lenovo Yoga 7 starts, suddenly, as soon as I can see the login screen, the monitor backlight gets dark. Even when I login it stays like this and I have to manually set illumination higher.
Any idea where this comes from or how to stop it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already check out the answers for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/796528/167115)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried it but no success. Instead of intel, I have amdgpu_bl0, just to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the answer was quite similar to the one mchid provided in his link.
So again, thanks for this hint.
The solution is **acpi_backlight=vendor** which can be done like this for example:

```
cd /etc/default
sudo nano grub
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor"
...
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

The value was taken from: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt