# Unable to adjust the brightness in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, brightness, backlight

I would like to control the brightness of my Laptop(HP Pavilion x360-Convertible) Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

I am not able to work for long hours with the current brightness.

I have tried the solutions mentioned in askubuntu.com such as

I) The Brightness keys on my laptop are not functional in Ubuntu 16.04. However they function correctly when booting in Windows 10

II) Installing brightness-controller application

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

But the resulting application did not work

III) Modifying brightness and max_brightness files in /sys/class/backlight

```
cd /sys/class/backlight
ls
```

It has no files. Thus can not proceed with this solution as well

IV) Installed xbacklightas and then tried to set the brightness, Even this did not work

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
xbacklight -set 50
```

gave no result

V) Also, installed Brightness Indicator via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

After rebooting, when clicking on the icon gives "No backlights were found in your system"

Could you please tell any working approach for my laptop

Comment: isnt there a brightness button on your laptop?

Comment: SOrry to not have mentioned this in my post: The brightness buttons on my laptop are not functional in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:
[Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04)

There is also a Ubuntu article on it:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

According to the top article:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
change line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to 

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

then save, exit and run:
    `sudo update-grub`

then reboot

Explanation is that acpi adds its own backlight control even if one is already present which is intel_backlight, adding this line forces acpi to use the intel backlight.

Comment: Doesn't work...