# Lower brightness than 1 on intel_backlight

Tags: brightness, intel, backlight

On performing this, 
    `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
I get the value as `1`, which is the lowest possible value but my screen is bright. Upon setting to `0` with `sudo su -c "echo 0 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"` the brightness doesn't change and the brightness controls (up and down) stop working. Is there any way I can lower the brightness below this value. The above command doesn't accept fractional values.

Comment: Does your screen backlight react to any change of the value in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`? If not I would suspect it's the wrong file.

Comment: Yup, it does. It reflects changes from any integer value of 1 and higher.

Comment: A dell perhaps? This might work http://askubuntu.com/a/481501/15811