# System monitor brightness reset to maximun after restart in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, brightness, backlight

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
Initially it won't support brightness options by default.
After i enable by following [Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04).

After whenever i restart my system, the brightness level will rollback to maximum.

How to can i preserve my last settings ?